# How to make svg image larger than parent div?

Tags: css

I have a parent div called profile-pic in a div wrapper. In the parent div resides an svg image. I need the svg image to be larger than the parent div so the svg image (barbed wire) looks like a border surrounding the parent div. I understand if I resize the child element (barbed wire) it will do no good. I also understand that resizing the parent element will do no good since the child element grows and shrinks with max-width of parent div size. If I try to set a width and height on the image bigger than the parent element it breaks. Here is what I have tried. [codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/LYyPzEK)

```
    <main>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="profile-pic">
                <img src="src/barbed-wire-circle.svg" alt="circle">
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>



body {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    background: #fffcd8;
}

main {
    height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: none;
}

main img {
    max-width: 100%;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 40s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: auto 50%;
    background-position: center;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from{ transform: rotate(-360deg); }
    to{ transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.wrapper {
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: none;
}

.profile-pic {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: auto 50%;
}
```

Comment: Using a pseudo before element for the barbed wire, positioned absolutely relative to the circle but larger might be useful since the barbed wire is decorative rather than naturally part of the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I needed to add another div called inner-profile with an absolute position. Then on the parent div profile-pic, display as flex with justify-content and align-items center. updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/LYyPzEK)

```
    <main>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="profile-pic">
                <div class="inner-profile"></div>
                <img class="" src="src/barbed-wire-circle.svg" alt="circle">
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>


.inner-profile {
    position: absolute;
    width: 470px;
    height: 470px;
    background-color: thistle;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.profile-pic {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: auto 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```